# How to disable WCF self-hosted localhost pc only service promotion of firewall port exception window?

Tags: c#, wcf, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm hosting local WCF service on TCP. On app start user receiving Firewall prompt to create firewall exception of port, my service is trying to use.

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(IMyService),
    new NetTcpBinding(),
    "net.tcp://localhost:18673/MyService");
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = false });
host.Open();
```

I'm just want to create local PC only service without opening port for local network and I don't want to firewall prompt appear to my app users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here [Hosting WCF locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793663/hosting-wcf-locally)

All i need is use `NetNamedPipeBinding` instead of `NetTcpBinding`.